# Why does gallium nitride allow an AESA radar to be more powerful than a radar with elements made of gallium arsenide?

Tags: electronic-configuration, materials

AESA (Actively Electronically Scanned Array) radars use thousands of individual transmit/receive elements to create a radar.  All in service AESAs use gallium arsenide as the material in the t/r elements.  It is said that gallium nitride allows a tenfold increase in the power emitted by these elements?  What allows GaN to emit so much more radio frequency energy than GaAs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that GaN transistors have a much higher breakdown voltage and saturation velocity than GaAs, allowing them to operate at higher voltages at high frequency, handling more power. The large band gap (~2x GaAs) means that GaN still behaves like a semiconductor, even at relatively high temperatures, allowing for higher operating powers.

GaN has really been a breakthrough in semiconductor technology. It's what allows us to have 405 nm violet laser diodes and could potentially replace magnetrons in microwave ovens. NXP has a little document [here](http://www.nxp.com/documents/external_articles/NXP_goes_with_GaN_July_2011.pdf) comparing GaN with a few older technologies that's a quick read.